# Invalid cast exception was unhandled when saving gridview to a file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

okay I am totally stuck.

I have been getting some help off and on throughout this project and am anxious to get this problem solved so I can continue on with the rest of this project.

I have a gridview that is set to save to a file, and has the option to import into excel.
I keep getting an error of this:

Invalid cast exception was unhandled.
At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type.

Can anyone tell me in layman easy to understand what this error is speaking of?

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
Dim fileName As String = ""
    Dim dlgSave As New SaveFileDialog
    dlgSave.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    dlgSave.AddExtension = True
    dlgSave.DefaultExt = "txt"
    If dlgSave.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        fileName = dlgSave.FileName
        SaveToFile(fileName)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub SaveToFile(ByVal fileName As String)
    If DataGridView1.RowCount > 0 AndAlso DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0) IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim stream As New System.IO.FileStream(fileName, IO.FileMode.Append, IO.FileAccess.Write)
        Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(stream)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim arrLine(9) As String
            Dim line As String
            **row.Cells.CopyTo(arrLine, 0)**
            line = arrLine(0)
            line &= ";" & arrLine(1)
            line &= ";" & arrLine(2)
            line &= ";" & arrLine(3)
            line &= ";" & arrLine(4)
            line &= ";" & arrLine(5)
            line &= ";" & arrLine(6)
            line &= ";" & arrLine(7)
            line &= ";" & arrLine(8)
            sw.WriteLine(line)
        Next
        sw.Flush()
        sw.Close()

    End If
```

I bolded the line where it shows in debug, and I really dont see what all the fuss is about LOL

Comment: That's got to be the worst question title ever..

Comment: You should make your question title more specific so that people will actually view this post.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume you only want the value of the cell, then your method is incorrect, as it will try to copy the entire cell to the array.

Would this work for you?

```
        //**row.Cells.CopyTo(arrLine, 0)**
        line = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()
        line &= ";" & row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()
        line &= ";" & row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()
        line &= ";" & row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()
        line &= ";" & row.Cells[4].Value.ToString()
        line &= ";" & row.Cells[5].Value.ToString()
        line &= ";" & row.Cells[6].Value.ToString()
        line &= ";" & row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()
        line &= ";" & row.Cells[8].Value.ToString()
        sw.WriteLine(line)
```

Comment: This is what you want.  Looks like DataGridViewRowCollection.CopyTo is expecting an array of DataGridViewRow objects, not an array of strings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.copyto.aspx

Comment: That didnt work :( it gave me the same error as before ..but thank you for the effort!

Comment: @Dcurvez The only reason you would be getting the same error ("At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type.") is if you did not comment out the line row.Cells[0].CopyTo(arrLine,0).  Unless you have another Array.CopyTo somewhere else.  Did you do this?

Comment: Jesus Matthew, I dont know. what I have so far....it has changed from previous because at this point I am reaching for straws.
    
    Dim arrLine(9) As String                Dim line As String                row.Cells.CopyTo(DirectCast(arrLine, Array), 0)                line = arrLine(0)                line &= ";" & arrLine(1)                line &= ";" & arrLine(2)                 sw.WriteLine(line)

this one gives me the cast down error

Comment: this one gives error stating arrLine is not declared:

    Dim arrLines As Array = New String() {}                Dim line As String                row.Cells.CopyTo(DirectCast(arrLine, Array), 0)                line = arrLine(0)                line &= ";" & arrLine(1)                line &= ";" & arrLine(2)

Comment: @Dcurvez The problem is the CopyTo function.  What happens if you comment out the line involving that function?

Comment: removing that line and running debug gave me an out of bounds error
on the line under it :  line = arrLine(0)
says Index out of range exception was unhandled,Index was out of bounds of the array.

Comment: @Dcurvez Good. Let's try this. Leave the line commented and replace everything from that line to the sw.WriteLine function with my answer. Does that change anything?

Comment: no Matthew it didnt work :( 

it gave me errors on all the lines at the point of line = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()on these lines it is not happy with the numbers in the brackets. It tells me Identifier is expected.

and the lines at the point of : 

line &= ";" & row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()

it is telling me on this that Operator '&' is not defined for types 'string'and 'system.windows.forms.DataGridViewCellCollection'

maybe if I replace the numbers with the actual column names?

Answer (score 0):

I generally try to avoid VisualBasic (the syntax always seems opposite to me), but from a little bit of Googling at the VB docs, I'd hazard a guess that you have a type mismatch between your string array (arrLine) and what row.Cells is trying to copy into it.

Comment: well, i am sorry for the bad title. didnt really give it much thought.

I tried the alterations above and ended p with the same error :(

Kitsune seems to strike a point as it was the first thought that came to mind, however I do not know how to fix this.